# yii ajax validation errors show up

Tags: ajax, validation, yii

I have the following form:

```
$form = $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
            'id'=>'new-agenda-entry',
            'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
            'action'=>'')); ?>
        <div class="four columns">
            <div class="right top5 sufix10">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'eventTime'); ?>
                <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                'name'=>'UserAgenda[eventTime]',
                'model'=>$model,
                'options'=>array(
                    'dateFormat'=>'yy-mm-dd',
                    'minDate'=>'new Date()',
                ) // jquery plugin options
            ));?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model, 'eventTime'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="right top5 sufix10">
                <?php echo CHtml::dropdownList('eventTime_hour', false, $this->getHourArray()); ?>
                <?php echo CHtml::dropdownList('eventTime_min', false, array('00'=>'00', '30'=>'30')); ?>
            </div>
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'note'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'note');?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model, 'note'); ?>
```

The model is successfully validated on the server as I can see the response in Firebug:

```
{"UserAgenda_eventTime":["Event time cannot be blank."],"UserAgenda_note":["Note cannot be blank."]}
```

The message seems fine, so does the html but the hidden inputs generated by yii remain hidden and empty.

Comment: make sure the parameters being validated are safe in the model rules

Comment: you'd look in your models rules. However since you can see the error messages in Firebug it seems that your rules already have those parameters in there so please ignore my initial comment. I was mistaken, it is not about your rules.

Answer (score 1):

in the action maybe (create or update) you have to uncomment `// $this->performAjaxValidation($model);` like this you have an ajax validation, if the problem persist I think posting it to yiibootstrap discussion in yii forums i better, I see that you use yiibootstrap, try it with default yii form widget.